# Don't know which relationship to use

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to create an application to learn words. Let's say I have a table learn_list, which has a foreign key user_id and word_id. User has one learn list, learn list has many words. Which relationship is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for all i understand by your statement is you have 3 table.
(i have taken random names just to make it simple)

```
user_list 
learn_list 
word_list
```

`user_list` will have one to one relationship  with `learn_list`
and `learn_list` will have one to many relationship with `word_list`

Below is a simple diagram to make it easy
[image: i have attached a simple diagram to make it easy]

Answer (score 0):

If your user has one learn list and this learn list can belong to many users, then your users table should have a learn_list_id column. LearnList model has a One to Many relationship with User model.

If your learn list has many words, then your words table should have a learn_list_id column. Learnlist model has a One to Many relationship model with your Word model.

Take a look at this guide https://hackernoon.com/eloquent-relationships-cheat-sheet-5155498c209